# How to select rows with certain values within a group in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I am training myself in loops and functions in R (but am at a really basic level at the moment). For a recent study, I need to prepare my data as following:

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
dd <- read.table(text="
    event.timeline.ys     ID     year    group
1                   2     800033 2008    A
2                   1     800033 2009    A   
3                   0     800033 2010    A   
4                  -1     800033 2011    A   
5                  -2     800033 2012    A   
15                  0     800076 2008    B
16                 -1     800076 2009    B
17                  5     800100 2014    C     
18                  4     800100 2015    C   
19                  2     800100 2017    C   
20                  1     800100 2018    C   
30                  0     800125 2008    A    
31                 -1     800125 2009    A    
32                 -2     800125 2010    A", header=TRUE)
```

I would like to keep for each person only the *last* row with event.timeline.ys >= 0 (this would be row 3 for ID 800033) and the *first* row with event.timeline.ys < 0 (this would be row 4 for ID 800033). All other rows would be deleted. My final data frame should therefore contain only two rows per ID.

The person with the ID = 800100 does not have any negative values on event.timeline.ys. In this case, I would like to keep only the last row with event.timeline.ys >= 0.

The final data set would then look like this:

```
    event.timeline.ys     ID     year    group  
3                   0     800033 2010    A   
4                  -1     800033 2011    A      
15                  0     800076 2008    B
16                 -1     800076 2009    B 
20                  1     800100 2018    C   
30                  0     800125 2008    A    
31                 -1     800125 2009    A
```

I thought about using a for-loop to check within each ID what the *last* row with event.timeline.ys >= 0 and the *first* row with event.timeline.ys < 0 is. However, the practical implementation in R fails.

Does anyone has a smart advice? I am also very open to other solutions that are not based on for-loops or similar stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option making use of `group_by` in dplyr:

```
dd %>% group_by(ID, category = event.timeline.ys >= 0) %>% 
  filter(abs(event.timeline.ys) == min(abs(event.timeline.ys))) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-category) %>%
  as.data.frame

  category event.timeline.ys     ID year group
1     TRUE                 0 800033 2010     A
2    FALSE                -1 800033 2011     A
3     TRUE                 0 800076 2008     B
4    FALSE                -1 800076 2009     B
5     TRUE                 1 800100 2018     C
6     TRUE                 0 800125 2008     A
7    FALSE                -1 800125 2009     A
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this lightning-fast help! I'm afraid I still have a lot to learn :) But this forum is super helpful! Thanks again!

Comment: I extended this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55970694/how-to-select-rows-with-certain-values-on-a-combination-of-two-variables-within - Does anyone have a smart advice on how to select the rows based on a combination of values on two other variables within a group?

Answer (score 1):

Group by `ID`, and whether the `event.timesline.ys` is negative. If it's negative, select (`slice`) the first row, otherwise select the last (i.e. row `n()`).

```
library(dplyr)

dd %>% 
  mutate(neg = event.timeline.ys < 0) %>% 
  group_by(ID, neg) %>% 
  slice(if(neg[1]) 1 else n()) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-neg)

# # A tibble: 7 x 4
#   event.timeline.ys     ID  year group
#               <int>  <int> <int> <fct>
# 1                 0 800033  2010 A    
# 2                -1 800033  2011 A    
# 3                 0 800076  2008 B    
# 4                -1 800076  2009 B    
# 5                 1 800100  2018 C    
# 6                 0 800125  2008 A    
# 7                -1 800125  2009 A
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to extract the indexes for the rows you are interested in with `which()` and `row_number()`

```
library(dplyr)

dd %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(row_number() == last(which(event.timeline.ys >= 0)) | 
         row_number() == first(which(event.timeline.ys < 0)))
```

I think it has the benefit of reading similar to the way you described what you are after in words so hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I like this solution because the code is really easy to understand! Would you be willing to help me again on a similar problem that has an additional twist? It's described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55970694/how-to-select-rows-with-certain-values-on-a-combination-of-two-variables-within

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(dd)[, .SD[c(last(which(event.timeline.ys >= 0)),
                          first(which(event.timeline.ys < 0)))],
                  by=ID]


       ID event.timeline.ys year group
1: 800033                 0 2010     A
2: 800033                -1 2011     A
3: 800076                 0 2008     B
4: 800076                -1 2009     B
5: 800100                 1 2018     C
6: 800125                 0 2008     A
7: 800125                -1 2009     A
```

Comment: I extended this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55970694/how-to-select-rows-with-certain-values-on-a-combination-of-two-variables-within - Does anyone have a smart advice on how to select the rows based on a combination of values on two other variables within a group?