# How to select rows with certain values on a combination of two variables within a group in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr

This is an extension of the R problem I asked earlier: [How to select rows with certain values within a group in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55853841/how-to-select-rows-with-certain-values-within-a-group-in-r)

I got great help on that issue, but it got a bit more complicated now and I hope to receive advices how to handle this.

My Data looks like this:

```
dd <- read.table(text="
    event.timeline.ys     ID     year    group  outcome
                 1                   2     800033 2008    A  3
                 2                   1     800033 2009    A  3
                 3                   0     800033 2010    A  NA   
                 4                  -1     800033 2011    A  2  
                 5                  -2     800033 2012    A  1  
                 15                  0     800076 2008    B  2
                 16                 -1     800076 2009    B  NA
                 17                  5     800100 2014    C  4     
                 18                  4     800100 2015    C  4  
                 19                  2     800100 2017    C  4  
                 20                  1     800100 2018    C  3   
                 30                  0     800125 2008    A  2   
                 31                 -1     800125 2009    A  1   
                 32                 -2     800125 2010    A  NA
                 33                  2     800031 2008    A  3
                 34                  1     800031 2009    A  3
                 35                  0     800031 2010    A  NA   
                 36                 -1     800031 2011    A  NA  
                 37                 -2     800031 2012    A  1", header=TRUE)
```

I would like to select only special rows within a group (ID). These rows should be selected according to the following procedure:

If possible I would like to keep the last row with a positive value on event.timeline.ys for each participant (i.e., last row within an ID-group with event.timeline.ys >= 0) in which the outcome variable is not NA but has a valid value (e.g., for ID == 800033 this would be row 2).

Additionally, I would like to keep the first row with a negative value on event.timeline.ys for each participant (i.e., first row within an ID-group with event.timeline.ys < 0) in which the outcome variable is not NA (e.g., for ID == 800033 this would be row 4).

In the special case of ID == 800076 that does not have any non-NA values on the outcome variable when event.timeline.ys < 0, I would still like to keep the first row in which event.timeline.ys < 0.

The person with the ID = 800100 does not have any negative values on event.timeline.ys. In this case, I would like to keep only the last row with event.timeline.ys >= 0.

All other rows should be deleted. The final data frame would look like this:

```
      event.timeline.ys         ID     year    group  outcome
2                     1     800033     2009    A            3
4                    -1     800033     2011    A            2  
15                    0     800076     2008    B            2
16                   -1     800076     2009    B           NA
20                    1     800100     2018    C            3   
30                    0     800125     2008    A            2   
31                   -1     800125     2009    A            1
34                    1     800031     2009    A            3
37                   -2     800031     2012    A            1
```

I very much appreciate advices on how to solve this problem. I already tried this:

```
dd %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(row_number() == last(which(event.timeline.ys >= 0 & outcome >= 0)) | 
           row_number() == first(which(event.timeline.ys < 0 & outcome >= 0)))
```

However, I then lose the row 16 (for ID == 800076) which is unfortunate.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
dd %>%
group_by(ID, event.timeline.ys>=0) %>%
arrange(ID, event.timeline.ys>=0, abs(event.timeline.ys)) %>%
filter(!is.na(outcome) | n()==1) %>%
filter(row_number()==1) %>%
ungroup() %>%
select(-one_of('event.timeline.ys >= 0'))
```

Output:

```
  event.timeline.ys     ID  year group outcome
              <int>  <int> <int> <fct>   <int>
1                -1 800033  2011 A           2
2                 1 800033  2009 A           3
3                -1 800076  2009 B          NA
4                 0 800076  2008 B           2
5                 1 800100  2018 C           3
6                -1 800125  2009 A           1
7                 0 800125  2008 A           2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate your help. I love to see that there are different ways to get to the same result. For someone not so familiar with pipes, functions and loops (like me, I'm just starting to train myself in R) this also looks like a clear and straightforward solution!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution using `dplyr` and `wrapr`'s pipe `%.>%`.
I'm adding `outcome_na` and arranging by it to meet a condition "does not have any non-NA values".

```
library(dplyr)
library(wrapr)

dd %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(outcome_na = !is.na(outcome)) %.>%
  bind_rows(
    filter(., event.timeline.ys >= 0) %>% arrange(outcome_na, year) %>% slice(n()),
    filter(., event.timeline.ys < 0) %>% arrange(desc(outcome_na), year) %>% slice(1)
  ) %>%
  arrange(ID) %>%
  select(-outcome_na)
```

Comment: Hey, I added another person in my data example above (ID == 800031). Using your code, I would get row 34 (which is correct) and row 36. However, in row 36 this individuals has NA on the outcome variable. I would like to get row 37 (the first row with negative value on event.timeline.ys that also has a valid value on the outcome variable. How do I have to adjust your code to get this?

Comment: @MarieB. You have to arrange `event.timeline.ys < 0` by `outcome_na` also, but this time in descending order since you want not last but first row.

Answer (score 1):

Just to keep in-line with my previous answer using `data.table` we can use `ifelse` condition to select rows

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dd)
dd[, .SD[na.omit(c(ifelse(any(event.timeline.ys >= 0 & !is.na(outcome)),
                          last(which(event.timeline.ys >= 0 & !is.na(outcome))), 
                          last(which(event.timeline.ys >= 0))),
                   ifelse(any(event.timeline.ys < 0 & !is.na(outcome)),
                          first(which(event.timeline.ys < 0 & !is.na(outcome))), 
                          first(which(event.timeline.ys < 0)))))],
   by=ID]


       ID event.timeline.ys year group outcome
1: 800033                 1 2009     A       3
2: 800033                -1 2011     A       2
3: 800076                 0 2008     B       2
4: 800076                -1 2009     B      NA
5: 800100                 1 2018     C       3
6: 800125                 0 2008     A       2
7: 800125                -1 2009     A       1
8: 800031                 1 2009     A       3
9: 800031                -2 2012     A       1
```